# Amazon payment integeration in Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, amazon-pay

I am facing issue in Amazon payment gateway while completing `checkoutsession`.

Error which I am facing:

```
status=422; response={"reasonCode":"InvalidCheckoutSessionStatus","message":"You tried to call an operation on a Checkout Session that is in a state where that operation is not allowed"}
```

**My code**:

```
public function completeCheckout(Request $request){
        $amazonpay_config = array(
            'public_key_id' => config('amazonkey.public_key_id'),
            'private_key'   => config('amazonkey.private_key'),
            'region'        => 'UK',
            'sandbox'       => true
        );

        $payload = array(
            "chargeAmount" => array(
                "amount" => "100",
                "currencyCode"=>  "USD"
            ),
             
         );

         $payload = json_encode($payload);

         try {
            $checkoutSessionId = $request->checkoutSessionId;
            // dd($checkoutSessionId);
            $client = new ApayAPI($amazonpay_config);
            
            $result = $client->completeCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId, $payload, $headers = null);
            if ($result['status'] === 200) {
                // dd($result);
                $response = json_decode($result['response'], true);
                return $response;
                // $response = json_decode($result['response'], true);
                // $amazonPayRedirectUrl = $response['webCheckoutDetails']['amazonPayRedirectUrl'];
                // echo "amazonPayRedirectUrl=$amazonPayRedirectUrl\n";
            } else {
                // check the error
                echo 'status=' . $result['status'] . '; response=' . $result['response'] . "\n";
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // handle the exception
            echo $e . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answer to a similar issue found here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535379/amazon-pay-sdk-completecheckoutsession-error

Comment: hi mzm i have read the given link discerption but in my case amazon in not returning **amazonPayRedirectUrl ** in my updateSession response

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that prior to sending a request to complete checkout session that 1/the buyer has been redirected to checkoutResultReturnUrl (returned in response to [update checkout session](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-api-v2/checkout-session.html#update-checkout-session)) and 2/ there are no constraints in the [constraint object](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-api-v2/checkout-session.html#type-constraint) returned from update checkout session.  If both of these conditions have been satisfied, know that complete checkout session must be requested within 24 hours of a buyer's redirect to checkoutResultReturnUrl or the checkout session will automatically cancelled.